Xcode Cloud fatal: Device not configured
We've been using Xcode Cloud for a year without any issues. Recently, our IT team switched authentication from LDAP to Azure SAML SSO. Since then, we've been getting the following error whenever Xcode Cloud launches a build:
"Run command: '/bin/rm -rf /Volumes/workspace/repository &> /dev/null && GIT_TRACE2_PERF=/tmp/git_trace2_perf GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=/tmp/git_trace2_event git init /Volumes/workspace/repository && GIT_TRACE2_PERF=.....etc." "could not read Username for 'http://bitbucket.***': Device not configured Command exited with non-zero exit-code: 128"

Any idea what we need to change to get things working again?
Thanks!
